# Identifying near continuous line features in a broken network

Tags: qgis, line, buffer

I have a line dataset which contains thousands of records, the network isn't continuous and it is broken in many locations. The aim is to find potential routes which are continuous in long sections, or only have small breaks in the network, such as 50m. I am currently working in QGIS.

The image below shows an example area.

[image: network example]

The network to the west contains some long segments, and even though they are gaps, they are typically less than 50m and I would like to be able to fill the gaps in the network (50m and below) so I have a continuous route. So it would look something like the below:
[image]

I have tried using buffers and creating centre lines, but not quite got to where I want it to be.

Comment: I'm not clear what your ultimate aim is. Maybe update the question so there's a specific objective. Is it to measure the length of each part of the network? If so, what about where there are junctions. Or is it something else?

Comment: A network with gaps isn't a network, it's *broken* network. It should be simple enough to find "dangles" which need repair and neighbors within distance, but you need to review each one before you assume connectivity through the gap. Unfortunately, your Question isn't very clear, and seems to span multiple platforms, which makes it difficult to answer. Please [Edit] this to improve focus on the one question you want answered

Comment: Thanks both. Sorry the question was not clear enough, I think I was probably trying to answer 2 or 3 questions in a single post and not concise enough about what the output should be. I have edited the post and tried to keep it more focused on what I need first and foremost.

Comment: It's going to be tricky - as you've already worked out, buffer and skeletonize has its issues. You could probably write an expression (or maybe PyQGIS code) to iterate through the endpoints of all lines and add a new line for any which are within 50m of each other. You may end up with triangles where three lines come together. And if there are lines that join near the middle of other lines, you will need a different tactic.

Comment: You could use `Join attributes by nearest` and specify the maximum distance  in qgis in which to join by but these will not follow bends in the road, it is good however for joining straight lines.